# GitHub Apps (not OAuth) - multiple callback URLs not using redirect_uri

Tags: github, github-app

I've created a new "GitHub App" (not "OAuth App") and added two Callback URL settings:

1. http://localhost/github
2. https://myapp.com/github

To install the app, I redirect the user to the following page:

```
https://github.com/apps/<my app>/installations/new?state=test&redirect_uri=https://myapp.com/github
```

However, after successful install the user is redirected to http://localhost/github instead of myapp.com.

Am I missing some extra setting or using wrong query string parameter?

Comment: " Request user authorization (OAuth) during installation" checkbox is checked (and needed) if that matters